# Oozie : Schedule task (Python script)

Tags: scheduled-tasks, oozie

how to schedule a local task on hadoop by using Oozie ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this can be accomplished by making use of ssh action.ssh to the edgenode and execute the command locally.In the ssh action you need to supply the host and the command to be executed.

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/DG_SshActionExtension.html

Also note that the oozie user should have passwordless ssh access to the node where you are executing the commands